Create a path structure that can be navigated like classes
Assume there is the following path structure in a storage account that I've created myself:
basepath (e.g. /mount/basefolder/)
├── folder_a
├── folder_b
├── folder_c
|   ├── folder_c1
|   ├── folder_c2
|   └── a_file.txt
|   └── folder_d
|       ├── another_file.csv
|       ├── folder_d1
└── folder_d2
    └── my_table.xlsx

I'd like to have a class (or something else) Path that returns the base path "/mount/basefolder/" when calling it. So, pasting Path to the console should return "/mount/basefolder/".
When writing Path. in my IDE and pressing tabulator the IDE should suggest the different options of the second hierarchy of folders/files: "folder_a", "folder_b", "folder_c" and "folder_d". Calling Path.folder_b should return "/mount/basefolder/folder_b/". When writing Path.folder_c.to the IDE it should suggest the options "folder_c1", "folder_c2" and "a_file.txt" and so on.
The idea is that I can easily navigate the paths that exist using dots and that calling it returns the string to the actual path in my storage account. But how do I build something like that? Of course, classes are required. I thought that StrEnums might help but I couln't figure out how to set it up :(.

Do you need to build it dynamically from the root dir? Anyway, you'll need to use recursive structure, when attributes of a Path class that refers to folders are again instances of Path class

@Sergius: Actually, I don't have to build it dynamically. I want to create the structure myself.

You may run into problems with files with special characters such as spaces and .. Actually, I don't see how the IDE would suggest a_file.txt unless the . was replaced with a different character. You could possibly overload the [] operator and use the class as a sort of dictionary of strings, but it may not be what you want

Besides what @SquareFinder already said, the IDE can only suggest statically defined attributes and can't possibly infer attributes dynamically set at runtime.

It's up for debate whether this is the right approach. Building a class with dynamic attributes is bizarre, although your use case is understandable.
This implementation recursively walks from the current directory through all subdirectories and files and builds an instance for each. When it reaches a file it can be accessed by dir.subdir.file1_txt, it is hard to understand the output at dir.subdir.file1 if you want to have dir.subdir.file.txt.
This can be initialised by p = Path() which used the current working directory or p = Path("/path/that/you/care/about").
import os


class Path:
    def __init__(self, base_path=None):
        self.base_path = base_path or os.getcwd()

        for root, _, files in os.walk(self.base_path):
            relative_root = os.path.relpath(root, self.base_path)
            parts = relative_root.split(os.sep)

            current = self
            for part in parts:
                if part != ".":
                    setattr(
                        current,
                        part,
                        Path(
                            os.path.join(
                                self.base_path, *parts[: parts.index(part) + 1]
                            )
                        ),
                    )
                    current = getattr(current, part)
            for file in files:
                setattr(current, file.replace(".", "_"), os.path.join(root, file))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.base_path

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)


Thank you for your great answert. But my intention was not to build up the structure dynamically but to determine it myself and to use the paths to create the files and folders that are part of the structure. How can that be done?

You can see how the attributes are constructed in the __init__ method. You want to do something like that using setattr.
